# Adding permissions to menu items by user role

Tags: angular, nebular

I would like to be able to show according to the role which elements I should see, I follow this: https://github.com/akveo/nebular/issues/274, but it doesn't work for me, currently it hides the menu for both roles

I want the user role to have access to the dashboard

app.module.ts

```
NbSecurityModule.forRoot({
      accessControl: {
          user: {
          view: ['dashboard']
        },
        admin: {
          view: ['*']
        }
      }
    })
```

page-menu.ts

```
{
        title: 'Main',
        link: '/pages/dashboard',
        home: true,
        children: undefined,
        data: {
          permission: 'view',
          resource: 'dashboard'
        }
      },
```

Answer (score 0):

Found some useful links for you, hope that helps:

https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin/issues/1160

https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin/issues/1779

Answer (score 0):

Role based view can be set in **Pages.components.ts**

1. Get the user role from the Authentication Service
2. Set the value of **hidden** to true or false based on the user role

```
export class PagesComponent  implements OnInit{

  currentUser: any;
  menu: NbMenuItem[]

  constructor(private AuthService: AuthenticationService) {
    this.currentUser = AuthService.currentUserValue;
   
}
ngOnInit(){

  this.menu = [
    {
       title: 'Main',
        link: '/pages/dashboard',
        home: true,
        children: undefined,
        data: {
          permission: 'view',
          resource: 'dashboard'
        },
      "hidden" : this.currentUser.roles[0]!='ROLE_ADMIN'? true:false

    }
}
```